# Perl Sort Perl hash of hash like structure by values

Tags: perl

I have this structure:

```
      '$self' => {

         'stepTimePercentage' =>{

                'id12' => {
                     'percentage' => '1.00'
                   },
                 'id15' => {
                     'percentage' => '30.00'
                   },
                 'id4' => {
                     'percentage' => '20.00'
                   },
                 'id9' => {
                     'percentage' => '15.00'
                   },
               }

           }
```

I want to sort this structure by the values of the 'percentage'. I tryed the following but i get the : "Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>)".

```
foreach my $key (sort{ $self->{stepTimePercentage}->{percentage}{$b} <=> $self->{stepTimePercentage}->{percentage}{$a} } keys %{$self->{stepTimePercentage}}) {
    print "$key - $self->{stepTimePercentage}->{$key}->{percentage} % \n";
}
```

Then I tryed this (and i get "Global symbol "$key" requires explicit package name"):

```
foreach my $key (sort{ $self->{stepTimePercentage}{key}{$b} <=> $self->{stepTimePercentage}{$key}{$a}} keys %{$self->{stepTimePercentage}}) {
    print ("$key - $self->{stepTimePercentage}->{$key}->{percentage} % \n");
}
```

Comment: My Perl is very rusty, so sorry if this is off base - can you use un-quoted string literals in hash look-ups? or should it be `$self->{"stepTimePercentage"}->{"percentage"}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. The key you are sorting on is at the second level of a three-level hash, so you want:

```
foreach my $key (sort { 
    $self->{stepTimePercentage}{$b}{percentage}
       <=> 
    $self->{stepTimePercentage}{$a}{percentage} 
} keys %{$self->{stepTimePercentage}}) {

    print "$key - $self->{stepTimePercentage}->{$key}->{percentage} % \n";

}
```

Comment: Now what if i have on the same level with 'percentage', another key->value element? will it be the same?